# Use Reflection.Emit to generate Types that reference each other

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reflection.emit

I want to generate Types via reflection at runtime that reference each other.

With static code I would do this

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

I can sucessfully generate my Order and my OrderDetails Type with the value type properties.

The code looks like this

```
var aName = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName("DynamicAssembly");
var ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
    aName, System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
var mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name);

var tb = mb.DefineType("Order",
    System.Reflection.TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(Object));

var pbId = tb.DefineProperty("Id", PropertyAttributes.None, typeof(int), null);
```

Now I am stuck at this line:

```
var pbCustomer = tb.DefineProperty("Customer", PropertyAttributes.None, ???, null);
```

I am required to pass the type of the property to the DefineProperty method but the type does not exist at this point.
Now I could just create a type builder for customer at this point and use `tb.CreateType()` to get the type but that would not help since Customer needs a reference to Order, too.

Comment: I know this example is probably simplistic, and the real scenario could be much more complex, but.. you have a circular reference. Can you break it by modifying your design? (Just curious)

Comment: first you must define your type with typebuilder.definetype method for order and customer ,then then pass that typebuilder object to the defineproperty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your last paragraph is roughly right, but `TypeBuilder` derives from `Type`, so you don't need to call `CreateType`.  That is, create type builders for each of the recursive types, *then* define the properties passing the respective builders themselves as the return types.

Comment: Thanks, that works. First I create a TypeBuilder for every type I need, then I add the Properties with PropertyType = TypeBuilder and at the very end I call `typeBuilder.CreateType()` for every TypeBuilder instance so I can use them at runtime.